# an example of convergence theorems

Tags: real-analysis

I have this question and I am not able to solve it.

> $\ f_n(x)= \frac{{n}^{3/2}x}{1+n^2x^2}$ , $x\in[0,1]$, $n\in N$
>
> Using convergence theorems, show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to
>  \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx\, =0$

I tried to find a dominated integrable function but I could not find it. This sequence is not increasing. So I could not use the monotone convergence theorem. I also tried to use the derivative of arctan(nx). How can I proceed? Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Do you really want to use convergence theorems? Because you can integrate that thing very easily using $u=x^2$...

Comment: Then the problem will be showing that $\frac{1}{\sqrt[]{n}}\log(1+n^2)$ goes to zero, which is way more efficient than using tools as MCT and DCT (I wonder if they work tho)

Comment: Thank you but the question wants me to use convergence theorems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM:

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{1+n^2x^2}{n^{3/2}x^{3/2}} &= \dfrac{1}{(nx)^{3/2}} + (nx)^{1/2} \\&= \dfrac{1}{(nx)^{3/2}} + \dfrac{(nx)^{1/2}}{3} + \dfrac{(nx)^{1/2}}{3} + \dfrac{(nx)^{1/2}}{3} \\
&\ge 4 \sqrt[4]{\dfrac{1}{(nx)^{3/2}}\cdot \dfrac{(nx)^{1/2}}{3}\cdot\dfrac{(nx)^{1/2}}{3}\cdot\dfrac{(nx)^{1/2}}{3}} \\&= \dfrac{4}{3^{3/4}}.\end{align}$$

Hence, $\dfrac{n^{3/2}x^{3/2}}{1+n^2x^2} \le \dfrac{3^{3/4}}{4}$, and thus, $\dfrac{n^{3/2}x}{1+n^2x^2} \le \dfrac{3^{3/4}}{4x^{1/2}}$, which is integrable on $[0,1]$.

You can then apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem in the usual way.

Comment: But that function is not in $L^1$

Comment: Fair point. I'll leave this for now

Comment: @zhw. I've modified the answer to use a different bound which does work!

Comment: Really? I get $f_n(1/n) =\sqrt n/2.$

Comment: As do I, but that's not a problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: You could also do this by maximizing $\dfrac{x^{3/2}}{1+n^2x^2}$ over $[0,1].$

Comment: I get the maximum occurs at $x= \sqrt 3 /n.$ This shows that $\dfrac{n^{3/2}x^{3/2}}{1+n^2x^2}$ is bounded, independent of $n.$ This shows the integrand is bounded by a constant times $1/\sqrt x.$

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you'd like to see, but here is my approach:
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_{x=0}^{1} \frac{n^{3/2}x}{1+n^2x^2} \mathrm{d}x=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_{x=0}^{1} \frac{n^{3/2}}{2n^2}\frac{2n^{2}x}{1+n^2x^2} \mathrm{d}x=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{3/2}}{2n^2} \left. \log(1+n^2x^2)\right|_{x=0}^{1}=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{3/2}}{2n^2} \left(\log(1+n^2)-\log(1)\right)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{3/2}}{2n^2}\log(1+n^2)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(n^2+1)}{2\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{2}\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(n^2+1)}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot0=0$$
Since $\log(n^2+1)$ grows asymptotically slower than $\sqrt{n}$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.